# Throwing away element in index,element tuples

Tags: list, haskell, list-comprehension, enumerate

New to Haskell, and trying to construct an `[[(Int, Int)]]` where each element is its corresponding grid position, constructed from another board `[[a]]`. Therefore a square `[[a]]` of side length 3 would create

```
[[(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0)]
,[(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1)]
,[(0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2)]]
```

(eventually I'll be iterating over this with a `map (map ...)` into a function of type `[[a]] -> (Int, Int) -> b` to create a `[[b]]`, so if I'm missing something massively easier, let me know!)

In Python I might do something like:

```
[[(x,y) for (x,_) in enumerate(board[y])] for (y,_) in enumerate(board)]
```

That is to say, I'd use the `enumerate` builtin to construct `(index, element)` tuples and throw away the element.

I know in Haskell I can do:

```
[[(x,y) | x <- [0..length (board!!y)-1]] | y <- [0..length board-1]]
```

but those sorts of constructions in Python (`for foo in range(len(bar))`) are a bit of an anti-pattern and heavily discouraged. Is that true in Haskell, as well?

If I were to write the Haskell like I'd write the Python, I'd do:

```
[[(x,y) | (x,_) <- zip [0..] (board!!y)] | (y,_) <- zip [0..] board]
```

Is that frowned upon?

Comment: More generally: in Python we talk about something being "Pythonic" if it's well-written and idiomatic. Is there a similar term here for a "Haskellion" construct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your final "write it like Python" suggestion is almost good, but you are unnecessarily throwing away the rows of the board, and then re-creating them with `(!!)`. Writing it like this instead would be perfectly fine:

```
board :: [[Char]]
board = ["abc", "def", "ghi"]

board' :: [[(Int, Int)]]
board' = [[(x, y) | (x, _) <- zip [0..] row]
                  | (y, row) <- zip [0..] board]
```

Comment: This is perfect. Not sure why I didn't think of this myself -- thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Well usually the [`(!!) :: [a] -> Int -> a`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:-33--33-) is not really a nice operator: it requires *O(k)* time to access the *k*-th element. For your small example that is of course not really an issue, but it can turn some algorithms from *O(n)* into *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*.

Usually in Haskell, one aims to avoid it by writing clever algorithms that can *iterate* through the list, instead of *obtaining a (random) index*.

In Python you can rewrite your:

```
[[(x,y) for (x,_) in enumerate(board[y])] for (y,_) in enumerate(board)]
```

into:

```
[[(x,y) for (x,_) in enumerate(by)] for (y,by) in enumerate(board)]
```

and the equivalent in Haskell would be:

```
[ [ (x,y) | (x,_) <- zip [0..] by ] | (y,by) <- zip [0..] board ]
```

Or we can make the code cleaner by first introducing an `enumerate :: (Enum a, Num a) => [b] -> [(a, b)]` function in Haskell:

```
enumerate :: (Enum a, Num a) => [b] -> [(a, b)]
enumerate = zip [0..]
```

and then write:

```
[ [ (x,y) | (x,_) <- enumerate by ] | (y,by) <- enumerate board ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your aside seems to suggest you might be interested in the following function, sometimes called `mapWithIndex` (e.g., [in `containers`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.10.2/docs/Data-Sequence.html#v:mapWithIndex)) and sometimes called `imap` ([in `lens`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.2/docs/Control-Lens-Indexed.html#t:FunctorWithIndex)).

```
mapWithIndex :: (Int -> a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
mapWithIndex f = go 0
  where
    go !_i [] = []
    go i (x : xs) = f i x : go (i + 1) xs
```

So `mapWithIndex (\i -> mapWithIndex (\j y -> (i,j,y)))` will take a list of lists and annotate each element with its position. Of course, rather than annotating, you can perform an arbitrary calculation.